# How to select the first sub-item in a list with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, selector

I know this is a really strange title, but I'll do my best to explain the problem below:

I have a page with a layout similar to the following:

```
.item
  pre
    code
  pre
    code
.item
.item
  pre
    code
```

I want to select the `code` items (because I want to loop through them with `'each()'`). However, I want to only select the *first* `'pre/code'` combo in each `.item` block.

How can I do this?

At first I had `$(".item pre code")`, which selects *all* of the `'pre/code'` combos. I noticed in the jQuery docs that there's a `:first-child` selector. I tried sticking it on the end of the `pre`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Close, `$('.item pre:first code')`

Comment: @mVChr: you should really make that an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `nth-child` selector.  This chooses the element that matches the argument (a 1-based index) for each of the parent selectors. (`:first` only returns the first `pre`; `nth-child` returns all `pre`s that are the first child of their parent:

```
$('.item pre:nth-child(1) code')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/syLMD/

NB that this is equivalent to `.item pre:first-child code`.  As far as I can tell, [that works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/syLMD/1/).

---

OK, with the knowledge that the first `pre` may not contain a `code`...  You can't do this with a simple selector. This needs more complex filtering:

```
$('.item')
    .data('found', false) // ensure that all item nodes have found = false
    .find('pre code') // find descendant code nodes
        .filter(function(){
            if ($.data(this.parentNode.parentNode, 'found')) { // if this item has already been found
                return false; // remove the code element from the selection
            } else {
                $.data(this.parentNode.parentNode, 'found', true) // mark the item as found
                return true; // keep the code element in the selection
            }
        })
            .each(function(){ // for each of these code elements
                $('#output').append(this.innerHTML); // or something else
            })
        .end() // back to the un-filtered selection of code elements
    .end() // back to the selection of div.item elements
    .data('found', false); // mark them as not found, for the next time
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/syLMD/4/).  Note that this isn't exactly going to have wonderful performance...

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/george_edison/syLMD/2/ If the first `PRE` doesn't contain a `CODE` element, then your example falls apart.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've accepted your answer, but you're right. Performance will be a little on the slow side.

Comment: @George I'd suggest you try to do this server-side if you can.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't :( This is a UserScript running on a third-party's site.